# .htaccess files, PHP, includes directories, and windows XAMPP configuration nightmare

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp, config

XAMPP makes configuring a local LAMP stack for windows a breeze. So it's quite disappointing that enabling `.htaccess` files is such a nightmare.

My problem:
I've got a PHP application that requires apache/php to search for an `/includes/` directory contained within the application. To do this, `.htaccess` files must be allowed in Apache and the `.htaccess` file must specify exactly where the includes directory is.

Problem is, I can't get my Apache config to view these `.htaccess` files. I had major hassles installing this app at uni and getting the admins there to help with the setup. This shouldn't be so hard but for some reason I just can't get Apache to play nice.

This is my setup:

`c:\xampp`
`c:\xampp\htdocs`
`c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` - where I've made the changes listed below
`c:\xampp\apache\bin\php.ini` - where changes to this file affect the PHP installation
It is interesting to note that `c:\xampp\php\php.ini` changes mean nothing - this is NOT the ini that affects the PHP installation.

The following lines are additions I've made to the `httpd.conf` file

```
#AccessFileName .htaccess
AccessFileName htaccess.txt
#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd
# files from being viewed by Web clients.
#
#<Files ~ "^\.ht">
<Files ~ "^htaccess\.">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs">
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in
# .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All
#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The following is the entire `.htaccess` file contained in:
`c:\xampp\htdocs\application\htaccess.txt`

```
<Files ~ "\.inc$">
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Files>

php_value default_charset "UTF-8"
php_value include_path ".;c:\xampp\htdocs\application\includes"
php_value register_globals 0
php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0
php_value magic_quotes_runtime 0
php_value magic_quotes_sybase 0
php_value session.use_cookies 1
php_value session.use_only_cookies 0
php_value session.use_trans_sid 1
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 3600
php_value arg_separator.output "&amp;"
php_value url_rewriter.tags "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,fieldset="
```

The includes directory exists at the location specified.

When I try to access the application I receive the following error:

```
Warning: require(include.general.inc) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\application\menu\logon.php on line 21
```

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required `include.general.inc` (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\pear\random') in `C:\xampp\htdocs\application\menu\logon.php` on line 21

The include path `c..\random\` is specified in the `php.ini` file listed above. The XAMPP install fails to allow another include path as specified in the `htaccess.txt` file.

I'm guessing there's probably an error with the `httpd.conf` OR the `htaccess.txt` file.. but it doesn't seem to be reading the `.htaccess` file. I've tried to be as thorough as possible so forgive the verbosity of the post.

Now I know a workaround could be to simply add the include_path to the PHP file, but I'm not going to have access to the `php.ini` file on the location I plan to deploy my app. I will, however, be able to request the server admin allows `.htaccess` files.

renamed `htacces.txt` to `.htaccess` and ammended the appropriate directives in the `httpd.conf` file and all seems to work. The application suggested the naming of `htaccess.txt` and the ammended directives in the httpd. These are obviously wrong (at least for a XAMPP stack).

By the way, using ini_set() is a much friendlier way if the app needs to be deployed to multiple locations so thanks especially for that pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Why do you need to rename .htaccess to htaccess.txt
2. Try setting the include_path using [set_include_path()](http://php.net/set_include_path()) and see if that helps (as an intermediate fix)
3. Verify which php.ini to use through a [phpinfo()](http://php.net/phpinfo)

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the include_path on each request using ini_set(). This would avoid having to use htaccess at all.

Answer (score 1):

My htaccess works under XAMPP fine - though some modules are disabled by default - are you sure that the modules you want are enabled?

Comment: I've enabled mod_rewrite .. are there other mods I need to enable?

Comment: mine needed mod_cache - I could tell it didn't work because when I had the .htaccess file around I got server errors - is that the same symptoms as you?

Answer (score 1):

I think the searchprase you are looking for is:

[AllowOverride All](http://www.google.com/search?site=&hl=en&q=allowoverride+all)

My guess is that within xampp you need to enable AllowOverride (through an .htaccess) in httpd.conf. It's a simple security measure that prevents newbies from installing a hackable platform :P

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable AllowOverride All in main http.conf file. Look inside XAMPP_DIR/apache/conf/http.conf)

Answer (score 1):

Simply Do this:

```
open file ...\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

find line "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so"

if here is a # before this line remove it.(remove comment)
```

its working