# XAMPP Version 5.6.11 : how to start xampp rewrite mode

Tags: xampp, url-rewrite-module

i have installed XAMPP Version 5.6.11

my question is, how to enable rewrite mode for url rewriting by using .htaccess

thank you

Comment: Have you tried setting AllowOverride All? There are a lot of existing StackOverflow posts with helpful information already

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess files, php, includes directories, and windows XAMPP configuration nightmare](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152823/htaccess-files-php-includes-directories-and-windows-xampp-configuration-night)

Comment: XAMPP does not implement any functions itself, it only bundles other software. Rewriting is a module for the bundled apache http server. So your questions is how to enable rewriting for the apache http server. That is documented and easy to find by google.

Answer (score 0):

follow :

1. open file ...\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf
2. find line "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so"
3. if here is a # before this line remove it.(remove comment)

its working